# Invisible PieChart labels?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, pie-chart, ireport

i try to use PieChart in iReport but labels are not visible... only the legend is visible.

What i have to do to make labels visible?

Thanks all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug of version 3.7.5, which was not solved in version 3.7.6. I suggest you move to the new version 4.0.0. Another option would be to go back to version 3.7.2. Once you have the correct version, just move to the Pie Chart Properties and configure them.

This is version 4.0.0.

[image: Labels And Legend]

Comment: I'm afraid the Label still does not work the way it should. No matter which one you use of {0}, {1} or {2}, or their combination, it will display correctly in the designer, but will only show you the Item Name {0} in your final report. It is an improvement from the previous two versions, but still not fixed.

Comment: Nice! If the labels just need to show the item name it will work well. I have placed a question in the JasperForge forum to seek a fix for percentages and amount. http://jasperforge.org/plugins/espforum/view.php?group_id=83&forumid=101&topicid=84343